Did Achebe base this on a particular real-life work?
Things Fall Apart ends with the British district commissioner imagining how he will write about the recent events in Umofia in a planned book with the working title of The Pacification of the Primitive Tribes of the Lower Niger.
While this work is clearly fictional (and as-yet unwritten, at the novel’s close), it certainly seems plausible that a British district commissioner might write a memoir, history, or monograph on that very subject. Did Achebe intend this as a lampoon of any particular work(s) or author(s)? Were there accounts from the British perspective that he relied upon while researching his novel?
